# Multi armed bandits with known reward estimates

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

Consider a bandit problem in which you know the set of expected payoffs for pulling various arms, but you do not know which arm maps to which expected payoff.  Can you design a regret minimizing algorithm that will achieve better bounds than UCB? 
My intuition for solving this problem is, to use UCB for a while and get the reward estimates and then we can map the given known expected payoffs with their corresponding arms. But I can not convince myself this would perform better than UCB. My question is, will this kind of information lead to less exploration and more exploitation kind of situation?

Comment: The gap-dependent UCB bounds are derived more or less by answering the question "how many samples do we need to distinguish between the best and second-best arms with high confidence".   Having side information about the true expected payoffs could reduce the number of samples needed and might get you a better bound, but I think it would take a bit of work.  The current bounds are $O(\frac{1}{\Delta}\log(T))$, so perhaps the side information could reduce the dependence on the gap, $\Delta$?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to the best arm identification problem, in which one aims at devising algorithms that identify the best arm in the shortest possible amount of samples.

Focus on the case with $K = 2$ arms, and let the expected rewards be $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, and hence the gap $\Delta = |\mu_1-\mu_2|$, be known.

The lower bound on the sample complexity states that the number of samples you need to identify the best arm with probability at least $1-\delta$ (even with known expectations) [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04589)] is

$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau] \gtrsim \frac{8}{\Delta^2} \log(1/\delta)
$$

Hence, the knowledge of the expectations does not help in the identification.